# Could a large number, such as 255.000255 be converted to it's RGB channels in a Shader language?

Tags: flash, shaders, color, floating-point, agal

If I had a Vertex Shader constant holding one float value, like:

```
255.000255
```

**Where:** The first 3 numbers are actually red (255), next three are green (000), then the last three are blue (255).

... Could I separate those values and pass them to a vertex-variant register for the Fragment Shader? I'm thinking it would involve a combination of opcode operations such as: fractional, subtraction, and multiplications?

Perhaps there is a simpler way to pass all 3 color-channels in one register value and extract them back in separate channels (within a low-level language)?

**- UPDATE -**

Alright trying to clarify my question a bit. The flow of execution would be:

- In Flash (in my case), pass the value 0xff00ff (Magenta) to a free Vertex Constant register of FLOAT_1 (so it only uses one field of that register).
- In AGAL, the Vertex-Shader would decompile the field's value into 3 separate values (R, G, B, [A will be taken care of with another constant]).
- Still in the Vertex-Shader, pass those 3 separate values to a Variant that will be used by the Fragment Shader (example: mov v0.rgb, vt0.rgb).
- In the Fragment Shader, draw the interpolated color of the Variant.

Really, all I'm asking is happening in the Vertex-Shader. Then again, now that I know large numbers consisting of more than 7 digits won't work, a value of 0xFFFFFF won't fit! (16777215 = 8 digits = shit outta luck!).

Maybe it's just not worth the hassle. But if someone knows a work-around the limitation, that would be cool. (Heck... maybe it could be split into two fields instead?)

Comment: Floats are stored in a fundamentally different way than Integrals (int, long, byte...) and there is no reliable way to just move the bits from one to the other: http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/76474-how-float-stored-internally.html You'll want to use math.

Comment: What are you trying to do that you need to do this? Perhaps there's a better way to achieve what you intend.

Comment: I'm trying to compress color information into one value (when passed in a constant register), and pull it out at the GPU level in it's 3 components. Basically trying to reduce the number of registers used to leave room for extra data.

Comment: @bigp: I recognize *what* you're asking to do. I'm asking *why* you're trying to do it. Do you have a specific issue where you've run out of "registers"? What are you using those registers for currently? Perhaps there's something else that can be done instead of this.

Comment: It's not so much that I ran into the issue "now" but I would like to experiment with using only one large value that would contain the color information I need, in the event that I need the remaining registers for other information (X, Y, U, V, rotation, alpha, texture ID, etc.). If its of any further clarification, it would be intended for 2D only, in AGAL.

Comment: You'd be better off encoding it as 16711935 (hex: FF00FF) than a float "255.000255".

Comment: @Random832, true, but as I've just mentioned in my update (just a few seconds ago), it's likely that method would fail too because large numbers such as plain white 16777215 (hex: FFFFFF) would exceed the Float limit.

Comment: @bigp Why will numbers with more than 7 digits not work? Every register has 128 bits, that makes 32 bits per components. That allows for *huge* numbers, way beyond 7 digits. But quite honestly I think what you're trying to do is rather silly and not really of practical use. It will make your code harder to read/maintain etc.

Comment: What would be the limit to a positive integer as a Float value?

Comment: @bigp: "it's likely that method would fail too because large numbers such as plain white 16777215 (hex: FFFFFF) would exceed the Float limit." That limit matters when you're trying to store it *as a float*. When you're just shoving a binary value into a memory address and telling someone to pretend that this bit-pattern represents a float, that's different. Granted, since you're using Flash, I don't know if you can do that.

Comment: Ok my bad, forgot that it could be declared as another data-type. It looks like I have only ***FLOAT_1, FLOAT_2, FLOAT_3, FLOAT_4*** and ***BYTES_4*** as data types that I can work with (when I'm assigning them from Flash to the Context3D Vertex-constants). I'll look more into but thanks, this might the key to my solution! :)

Comment: @NicolBolas, Thanks btw for creating those new tags. I didn't have the power to add AGAL yet (or thought that it'd be best to categorize it as 'flash' as well). Finally! A StackExchange site that has 'agal'!

Comment: Note that 16777215 does _not_ exceed the “6 or 7 digits” limit on IEEE 32-bit floats. That limit is actually 7.2247 decimal digits, _ie._ 24 binary digits. 16777215 happens to fit exactly in those 24 digits. It does, however, exceed the minimum requirement for high resolution floats in GLES 2.0 shaders, which is 16 binary digits.

Answer (score 4):

Usually shader languages come with special types that hold multiple values.
For example GLSL has `vec2`, `vec3`, and `vec4` types which hold 2, 3 or 4 float values... these types are ideal for something like RGB or RGBA values.

I don't know which shader language you use, but from your other question I'm guessing it's AGAL (Flash shader). There you use register and every register is 128bits wide. So it can hold 4 float values, which you can access like this:

```
register.r // first component (red)
register.g // second component (green)
register.b // third component (blue)
register.a // fourth component (alpha)
```

If that's not a possibility, you could probably just use an integer and bitwise operations to get the color values. Eg something like this

```
uint color = 0xff6633;
red = (color >> 16) & 0xff;
green = (color >> 8) & 0xff;
blue = color & 0xff;
```

Comment: Bingo on guessing I was using AGAL :)

Comment: Hmm, I understand how to split up an integer value in its color channels via the use of Bitwise Operations, but I'm not sure they are supported in AGAL.

Comment: @bigp it doesn't look like bitwise operations are supported in AGAL nor Pixel Bender. But maybe writing the shader in Pixel Bender would be simpler.. it's higher level and has a feature set and types comparable with other shader languages.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't.

Floating-point numbers have a *floating* decimal point. So while you may write them as "255.000255", the float is stored exponentially: "2.55000255x10<sup>2</sup>".

As you may know, 32-bit floats only store 6-7 decimal digits of precision. 2.55000255 has nine digits. So you can kiss the last 255 goodbye.

Now, you *can* store it as an integer. In DX10/OpenGL3.x-class hardware and better, you have sufficient bit manipulation capabilities to pack 3-4 floating-point values into a 32-bit unsigned integer, and then restore them in the fragment shader. However...

I'm going to assume that by "vertex-variant register for the Fragment Shader", you mean "pass a value from the vertex shader to the fragment shader, which will be interpolated across the primitive in question." Well, that's a problem. Because linearly interpolating that 32-bit unsigned integer does *not* give rise to a reasonable value. At least, it doesn't do a proper blend between colors.

So unless you want to pass an un-interpolated value (or pass 3 uninterpolated values and do the interpolation yourself per-fragment), this is not possible.

Comment: Ok but if the integer was then converted to an acceptable range (between 0.0 and 1.0) for each color channels in the register to be passed (interpolated as you mentioned) to the fragment shader, then it would be safe right?

Comment: @bigp: There is a difference between interpolating 3 values and interpolating one value that pretends to be three. You cannot interpolate 3 values if they're stored in one value; attempting to do so will yield garbage. Furthermore, this is all irrelevant, because you can just do what bummzack said and just use more than one value. Registers have fields, each of which is a float. Use those fields, just like everyone else. That's what they're for.

Comment: What if you run out of registers / fields? And yeah I understand how three values piled up into one would create garbage interpolated results, but they wouldn't be at that point. I mean't to say one constant register field would have the 3-values-in-one, the vertex-shader would split it up, then it would pass the RGB value to the variant as @bummzack suggested.

Comment: @bigp: Then your question is incomplete and needs clarification. As I said, my answer assumes "vertex-variant register for the Fragment Shader" means "pass a value from the vertex shader to the fragment shader, which will be interpolated across the primitive in question." If that's not true, you need to fix your question to better describe what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Updated, hope it's a bit more clear.

Comment: Okay actually, what could be the largest positive integer stored in a float value? Shall I ask that in a separate question?